Why routing orthogonal signals with reference to the same plane?
In the book "ELECTROMAGNETIC COMPATIBILITY ENGINEERING" from Henry W. Ott it is often mentionned that orthogonally routed signals should reference the same plane. But I don't understand the reasons behind this recommendation. What is the explanation?

Can you provide a page number?

Look at the return path of the coupled signal between the two traces. If they share the same reference plane, the return path is ok. If the two traces refere to different reference planes, everything can happen. Imagine that the two planes are connected by an inductor -> your coupled signal passes through the inductor -> heavy noise.

But the reason for orthogonal (sometimes called X-Y) routing on adjacent layers is to minimize the coupling between traces on the two layers.  And in every design I've seen the two reference plans are the same (GND, for instance) or tightly couples (VCC & GND) by means of many decoupling caps.

@SteveSh yes, orthogonal routing does a great job at reducing the coupling. However it never gets to zero.

@SteveSh I agree that two reference planes might be ok. I assume the book (I dont know it personally) requires a single reference plane for the reson mentioned in my answer. But I would tend to argue that two tightly coupled planes can be considered as a single reference plane for this question.
There is, of course, also the option that there is an other phenomena I am not aware of. If you have an idea, feel free to comment or post an answer.

Thank you very much for your replies
